# Trying to Choose Color

Tags: java

I'm Trying to choose a color from the JColorChooser via the MouseEventClicked and then set the color chosen to the penColor but for some reason it's not working. I think i have a problem in the MouseClicked function.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Paint3<penColor> extends JFrame implements MouseMotionListener, MouseListener, ChangeListener {

int size = 2;
private Point pt = new Point();
private JSlider penSize = new JSlider(JSlider.VERTICAL,1,10,3);
JColorChooser jc = new JColorChooser();
public Color penColor = new Color(0,0,0);


public JPanel DrawingPanel = new JPanel(){
    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g.fillOval((int) pt.getX(), (int)pt.getY(), 5,5);
    }
};

public Paint3(){
    super("My Painter");
    Label l1 = new Label("Drag Mouse To Draw");
    JPanel jp2 = new JPanel();
    this.add((DrawingPanel), BorderLayout.NORTH);
    DrawingPanel.add((l1),BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add((jp2),BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    jp2.add(jc);
    this.addMouseMotionListener(this);
    this.addMouseListener(this);
    this.add(penSize, BorderLayout.EAST);
    penSize.addChangeListener((ChangeListener) this);
    penSize.setMinorTickSpacing(1);
    penSize.setPaintTicks(true);
    setSize(700,700);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


}

@Override
public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent me){
    Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D)getGraphics();
    g.setStroke(new BasicStroke(size));
    g.setColor(penColor);
    g.drawLine(pt.x,pt.y, me.getX(), me.getY());
    pt = me.getPoint();
}

@Override
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent me){
    pt = me.getPoint();
}

@Override 
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
    if(me.getModifiers()== MouseEvent.BUTTON3_MASK){
        //penColor = jc; //(this, "Change Pen Color" , penColor);
        //penColor = jc.getColor();
        penColor = jc.getColor();
    }
}


@Override 
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me){}

@Override 
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me){}

@Override 
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){}

@Override 
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me){}

@Override
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent me){
    JSlider source = (JSlider)me.getSource();
    if(!source.getValueIsAdjusting()){
        size = (int)source.getValue();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    new Paint3();
}
```

}

Comment: In your program, `penColor` is a `java.awt.Color` object. What do you wanna do with it?

Comment: Basically i want to Choose a color from the color chooser and then set that color to the penColor object. But it doesn't change the color.

Comment: What do you expect jc.getColor to return to you? Are you expecting a new color always?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, just try this code:

```
@Override 
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me){ 
penColor = jc.getColor(); 
}
```

You will modify the color in the **mousePressed** and not in the **mouseClicked**

I hope it will help you, best regards

Comment: It worked. Thank you for taking the time and correcting it! :D

Comment: Welcome Dear :) don't forget to mark my answer as true :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to do it. A `MouseListener` doesn't work on a `javax.swing.JColorChooser` the way you expect it to. Alteast not as the way you have mentioned in your post.

You need to import `javax.swing.colorchooser.ColorSelectionModel` and add a `javax.swing.ChangeListener` to it.

```
JColorChooser jc = new JColorChooser();
ColorSelectionModel model = jc.getSelectionModel();
model.addChangeListener(

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent event) {

        penColor = jc.getColor();
    }
);
```